# How can I check if a value pair already exists in the database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In VB.Net, I am trying to check if a certain value pair already exists in the database. If not, it needs to be added:

```vb
Public Shared Sub updateChoice(ByVal dbConn As NS.DBConn, ByVal Y As String, ByVal Z As Int32)
    'check if the Y <=> Z pair already exists
    Dim sqlText As String = "select from table where X = " & CStr(Y)" and Y =" &CStr(Z)
    Dim pairExists = dbConn.ExecuteAsDataSet(sqlText)

    If (pairExists <= 0) Then
        Dim sqlText As String = "insert into table ..." ' Insert pair into DB
        dbConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText)
    End If
End Sub
```

Visual Studio gives me an error on `If (pairExists <= 0) Then`: `Operator <= is not defined for types System.Data.DataSet and Integer`

I am having a hard time understanding this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The message is clear . pairExists is a DataSet, not an integer. You cannot compare theses two types together.

Comment: Then am I using the wrong method? I just want to check if the pair already exists and need pairExists to be assigned with an integer or TRUE / FALSE?

Comment: You want to use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteasDataset but your query is shown without any columns so make sure you fix that and define just one column in the select clause.

Comment: Thanks! Found ExecuteScalar myself also in the mean time :) Now it says `Option Strict On prohibits operands of type Object for operator <=`. So if I need to keep Option Strict, how do I need to make the comparison?

Comment: Cast the result from Object to integer

Comment: `If (DirectCast(pairExists, Integer) <= 0) Then` Thanks. First time OO-coding (from procedural PHP). Makes me nervous :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient to do the check and the insert in the same statment, it also significantly reduces the chance of meeting a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) by reducing the time between the check and the insert. The statement you would want is:

```
MERGE Table WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
USING (VALUES (@X, @Y)) AS s (X, Y)
    ON s.X = t.X
    AND s.X = t.Y
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (X, Y) VALUES (X, Y)
OUTPUT $action;
```

Using `MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK` is the best way I know of to avoid a race condition, however it is not a substitute for a unique constraint. If the values should be unique in the table then this should still be enforced with a constraint. You can then simply check the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`, it will return 1 if a row is inserted, 0 if the pair already exists.

You should also be using parameterised queries!